# Init System Sound Services (with NSData)

Tags: objective-c, audio

How to init System Sound Services with NsData ?

```
NSString *pewPewPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
pathForResource:@"pew-pew-lei" ofType:@"caf"];
NSURL *pewPewURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pewPewPath];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)pewPewURL, &self.pewPewSound);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(self.pewPewSound);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a **LOT** of error checking in your code.

```
NSString *pewPewPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pew-pew-lei" ofType:@"caf"];
if(pewPewPath)
{
    CFURLRef pewPewURL = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pewPewPath];
    if(pewPewURL)
    {
        OSStatus errorCode = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(pewPewURL, &self.pewPewSound);
        if(errorCode)
        {
            NSLog(@"error in creating the system sound - %ld", errorCode);
        } else {
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(self.pewPewSound);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"couldn't make pew-pew-lei into a URL");
    }
} else {
    NSLog( @"no pew-pew-lei.caf file found");
}
```